# Variables cannot be resolved error in an activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to check if several values introduced are in the database or not. I defined a SQLHelper class and the activity. I'm trying accessing those variables that are in the SQLHelper class from the activity but I can't because there is the following error:

longitud cannot be resolved

Variables that cannot be resolved are: nombre, longitud, latitud.

The code:

SQLOpenHelper:

```
package com.app.mapa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class Bdoh extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
SQLiteOpenHelper sbd;
static String T_NOMBRE="lugares"; //para el content provider
private static final String NOMBRE_BD = "Sitios";
private static final int VER_BD = 1;
private static final String bdcons = "CREATE TABLE " + T_NOMBRE + 
"(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nombre TEXT, descripcion TEXT, latitud  
    DOUBLE, " + "longitud DOUBLE, foto TEXT)";

    public Bdoh(Context context) 
{
    super(context, NOMBRE_BD, null, VER_BD);
    SQLiteDatabase  
            db=context.openOrCreateDatabase(NOMBRE_BD,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null); 

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    db.execSQL(bdcons);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lugares");
      db.execSQL(bdcons);
    }
}
```

The activity:

```
public boolean iguales()
{
    boolean ig = false;
    Uri urititl = MCProvider.CP_URI;
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(urititl,null,null,null,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    if(c.moveToFirst())
     {
        if((titlugar.equals(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(boh.nombre))))  
                      &&  (lat.equals(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(boh.latitud)))) && 
                      (lgt.equals(c.getDouble(bdoh.longitud)))) 
        ig = true;
        else ig = false;
     }

    return ig;
}
```

How can I access them?

Thanks.

Comment: @JustinJasmann  Please think.  If there is a variable unresolved error, how is the OP supposed to get a logcat?

Comment: My apologies, I made an assumption that their the unresolved variables  were inside the `bdcons` String variable, referencing database columns, which would occur at runtime.

Comment: @JustinJasmann An unresolved variable error can never occur at runtime.

Comment: @Simon What about a `select` statement on a database that doesn't contain that field?

Comment: @JustinJasmann Then you would get a "column does not exist" exception.  As I have said, it is impossible to get an unresolved variable at runtime since it is a compiler error.  You will not be able to build with unresolved variables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'boh' and 'bdoh' in your code are objects of type `Bdoh`.

The variables you mentioned cannot be resolved because your `Bdoh` class **does not have member variables with that name**. So the following cannot work:

```
if((titlugar.equals(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(boh.nombre))))  // boh.nombre does not exist
```

You need to **define** these member variables for your `Bdoh` class before you can use them like that.

For example:

```
public class Bdoh extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public String nombre;
    public String latitud;
    // and so on...
}
```

Please also try to format your code and question properly.

Also note that I think what you are "*practicing*" here is very bad style and should be done via getter and setter methods, or generally in a totally different way. As I do not want to expain the whole OOP concept, I can only recommend reading tutorials about Object-Oriented-Programming for example.

Comment: Yes. But what I want to do is to access databases fields named nombre, longitud and latitud and I don't know how to do it. If I define them how can I bind them to database fields?

Comment: Error fixed. I used getContentResolver and Strings to make the query.